# Dialogflow(Api.Ai) Doesn't recognize custom entity

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

I have been working lately with Dialogflow to make chatbots to do some simple tasks. For instance with webhooks and youtube api where the user ask to show  him a video and then the bot just answers with the youtube video url.

E.G.
USER SAYS 
Show me Neil young harvest moon

AGENT SAYS
Here you go : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2MtEsrcTTs

I do this by using a custom Entity I called "YoutubeQuery" I checked "Allow Automated expansion" and unchecked "Define Synonyms" then I just added 2 values "Kavinsky Night Call" and "Indigo Night Tamino"

[image: Entity with example values]

In my Intent I just made a couple of training phrases like these:

[image: Training Phrases for my youtube intent]

And everything works.

Now my issue is with a new Agent which I called Orders

I want just to get Order Id's from the firestore database, but before getting there I'm running in kind of a huge problem

I defined the order's ID entity just like the one with the youtubeQuery. And I added some example Order ID's , I want them all to Start with OD and have 4digits after example (DX0001,DX0009,DX9999)
[image: order id's entity]

Afterwards I made the intent 
[image: Intent of GetOrder]

Now unless I give the EXACT order ID's from the traininphrase or the ID examples I defined in the Entity it will always give me a response with an empty parameter OrderID 
I start my intent by saying "my order" then I get prompted with "What is your ID?

[image: intent start]

So when I give an ID that has not been used in the training phrases of the Intent I get an empty value  in the parameters like this:

[image: returning empty]

But when I give an ID that has been used in the training phrases like for instance the first one DX0808 it does work...

[image: Works]

How can I make this work without adding all the possible order id's ranging from DX0001 to DX9999 in the training phrases or the entity. 
I mean it does work for my youtube query, I can put anything there it does "catch" the value. Any help please?

Comment: Hi! Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557235/dialogflow-match-intent-if-phrase-is-ever-present/53557955?noredirect=1#comment94168309_53557955) and see if that works for you!

Comment: I tried it, but it only works if I put the parameters as NOT required, once I put it as required it doesn't work :/

Comment: I tried with @sys.any and it seems to work, but I don't know why it doesn't work with custom entities.

Comment: @sai.raj any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the required parameter is the problem here, my suggestion would be to:

1. **Create intent to get the order id in one sentence without reprompt** (turn off required on the order id) and id is always present, ex: "my id is DX0402". Include training response where only ID is provided like "DL3932", ex. below:

[image]

2. **Set other intent for scenario when customer wants to provide the id but it is missing**, for ex. customer says: "my id" and make your bot ask for the id as an response ex. "ok, provide me your id"

If you do it, in case user doesn't provide the id, intent 2 will be triggered and after id is provided you'll trigger intent 1.

Hope this makes sense.